# GRPC Golang custom data encryption

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

In grpc-go newHTTP2Client creates new conn with tls encryption by default with function ClientHandshake. How can i change default implementation of interface with this method for custom encryption ( change struct in param ConnectOptions->TransportCredentials )?

I found way to encrypt only proto message with custom codec implementation, but i need full conn data encryption

Comment: Like using TLS ?

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj Yes. I want just implement TransportCredentials with my own encryption and data will encrypt with my own method

Comment: Well you can do it in application level. Change the method to a single one “process” that receive a slice of bytes. This method will decode and route the right method / params, cypher it back to your client

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj but i need to do that without changing grpc code ( like implementation codec with mine and RegisterCodec -> ForceServerCodec in my server level )